# StopIteration unexpectedly raised during file multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to process 110 sets of 4 files : i.e 440 files total
The files will all have an identical number of lines (  10.4 million i ) and so the way my for loop is structure no iterator should finish before the others the way my code is structured.

The files are parsed into a collections.Counter object and the Counter dicts aggregated for further analysis

I am having irreproducible StopIterations in my code ,sometimes I get a StopIteration in 1 multiprocessing process and sometimes in two out of the four processes with the same input data. What am I doing wrong ? I never get stop iterations with a smaller amount of test data .

My pseudocode

```
  def main(*args):
        #code that sets up dicts to route Counter data

        def dict_populator_worker_process(*input_file_tuple_list):
            worker_dict = Counter()
            my_subproc_read_dict = defaultdict(list)

            for index_file1 , index_file2 ,run_file1,run_file2 in input_file_tuple_list:
                index1_file_handle = open(index_file1,"rUb")
                index2_file_handle = open(index_file2,"rUb")
                run1_file_handle = open(run_file1,"rUb")
                run2_file_handle = open(run_file2,"rUb")
                for line in index1_file_handle:
                    index2_file_handle.next()
                    index_for_read = (index1_file_handle.next().strip(),index2_file_handle.next().strip())
                    worker_dict.update((index_for_read,))
                    for i in range(4):
                        try:
                            # THIS IS WHERE I SHOULD NOT BE Exhausting the Iterator 
                            my_subproc_read_dict[(index_for_read,1)].append(run1_file_handle.next())
                            my_subproc_read_dict[(index_for_read,2)].append(run2_file_handle.next())
                        except StopIteration:
                            # sometimes get this undeservedly
                            pass
                    # logger.info(index_for_read)
                    index1_file_handle.next() # Handles the +
                    index2_file_handle.next() # Handles the +
                    index1_file_handle.next() #Handles the Q
                    index2_file_handle.next() # Handles the Q

            # logger.info(worker_dict.keys())
            pid = multiprocessing.current_process()
            pickle.dump(worker_dict,open("counter_dict_{}.p".format(pid),"wb"))
            pickle.dump(my_subproc_read_dict,open("my_subproc_read_dict_{}.p".format(pid),"wb"))
```

I want to know why I get a StopIteration if the iterators march in step and all files have equal number of lines ( setup by linux shell split, including the tail file which is equal). To setup the files , I do something like this.

```
all_index_file_tuples = zip(glob.glob("file1*pat.txt"),glob.glob("file2*pat.txt"),glob.glob("file3*pat.txt"),glob.glob("file4*pat.txt"))


chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(all_index_file_tuples) / float(NUM_PROCS)))
procs = []

for i in range(NUM_PROCS):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=dict_populator_worker_process , args = (all_index_file_tuples[chunksize * i:chunksize * (i + 1)]))
    procs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

Comment: Did you tried a debugger (pdb?) ? file.next() raises a StopIteration when the file reaches EOF.

Comment: Are `run_file1`/2 modified by other processes? Did you consider the possibility that your initial assumption is wrong and that your program proves that your files do *not* have an equal number of lines?

Comment: Run file 1 and 2 are not modified by other processes, but it may be that the subprocesses call to split is leaving a file open and causing issues.  I checked the files with a wc -l run1* etc and am a 100% certain they are equal in lengt . So maybe I'll explicitly close flehandles after the split which is part of the same script and get away from this issue.